# How do I access other installed apps' info.plist in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to check the versions of other installed apps on my iPad from within my app. I know this information is stored in their info.plist files.

How can I access the plist of other installed apps programmatically?  My apps are not published on the app store, so private methods are acceptable.

Comment: I cannot remove it; flag the question for moderator attention.  But the answer is that you have no access to the `info.plist` files of other apps.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have added the Custom URL scheme for my apps...would it be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are right, these values are stored in the `Info.plist` - more specifically, under the `CFBundleShortVersionString` and (should you need this too), a build number under the `CFBundleVersion` key.

`NSBundle` has a method called `infoDictionary` which returns the bundle's `Info.plist` (your app's if initialized using `mainBundle`), so in theory you should be able to load any application bundle this class.